# Using ReactiveUI to wire up Viewmodel and model

Tags: mvvm, reactiveui

How do I wire up Viewmodel and model the ReactiveUI way?
Is there even a ReactiveUI way (like this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged for normal properties)?

Regards
Tobias

Edit: small Sample:

```js
public class TestModel
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}

public class TestViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private TestModel _model;

    public TestViewModel(TestModel model)
    {
        _model = model;
    }

    public TestName
    {
        get
        {
            return _model.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            //Update model value and raise PropertyChanged, but how?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What part are you trying to wire up? Could you show an exampel of the VM and Model?

Comment: I added a small sample, hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string TestName
{
    get
    {
        return _model.TestName;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_model.TestName == value) return;
        _model.TestName = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

You could wrap this up in an extension method that takes an expression to know which field to update.